# Not able to install; vue/cli in mac

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I tried install vue cli using below command

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

getting below error

`npm ERR! Unexpected token } in JSON at position 5049 while parsing near '...-/recast-0.4.13.tgz"},"engines":{"node":...'`

I tried with sudo also.

After that I tried

`npm cache clean --force`

still facing the above error.

Please help out.

Comment: For your information, You could also install it locally by `npm install @vue/cli` and use the command something like `node_modules/.bin/vue`

Comment: If you are trying to install `@vue/cli` in existing app, please share your `package.json` also.

Comment: I tried ```npm install @vue/cli``` this also but getting the same error. @jogesh_pi

Comment: @SMAKSS I want to install it globally so that I can create new vue cli app

Comment: what version of npm are you using?